# Using Double Integral Find the volume of sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2= 4 $ cut by cylinder $\ x^2+y^2=2y $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Using Double Integral Find the volume of sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2= 4 $ cut by 
cylinder $\ x^2+y^2=2y $ , When i try to make integral the limits are:

$\ -1<= x<=1 $ and $\ 0<=y<=2 $ ,but i dont know what funtion i can use to find the volume.

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{2} f(x,y) \,dy\, d x$$

Answer (score 3):

The volume $V$ of a body $K$ is by definition
$$
V=\iiint_K 1\,dx\,dy\,dz.
$$
If you first integrate with respect to $z$, then, since the upper and lower limits for $z$ are the surfaces $z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and $z=-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ (see the picture below) you get
$$
V=\iint_D\bigl(\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}-(-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2})\bigr)\,dx\,dy.
$$

[image: cylinder and sphere]

Now, what is the domain $D$? It is *not* given by the inequalities $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 2$ as you seem to imply. Instead, what one should do is that one should project the body $K$ onto the $xy$-plane orthogonally. If we look at the picture below, we find out that $D$ is exactly the disk $x^2+(y-1)^2\leq 1$.

[image: cylinder and sphere from above]

> Thus, the volume $V$ you are looking for is given by the double integral $$V=\iint_D 2\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy$$ where $$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbf R^2~|~x^2+(y-1)^2\leq 1\}.$$

I leave it to you to continue the calculations.

Comment: $\ x^2 +(y-1)^2 <=1  $ , for radio of cylindrer?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find a volume of this kind of solids, just take the function to be equal to 1. 
Then you simply get $4$ as an answer.

Comment: Who? , can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed $f(x,y,z)=1$ 
$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & x=r\cos \theta  \\ 
 & y=r\sin \theta  \\ 
\end{align} \right.\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,J=r$$
we have
$$-\sqrt{4-{{r}^{2}}}\le z\le \sqrt{4-{{r}^{2}}}$$
and
$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & {{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}=4 \\ 
 & {{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}=2y \\ 
\end{align} \right.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\,2\sin \theta \le r\le 2$$
therefore
$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{2\sin \theta }^{2}{\int_{-\sqrt{4-{{r}^{2}}}}^{\sqrt{4-{{r}^{2}}}}{r\,dzdrd\theta }}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Volume will be equal to 
$$V=\int_{z=-2}^2\int_{y=0}^{\frac {4-z^2}{2}}\int_{x=-\sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}}dxdydz=\frac{112}{9}$$ hope this will be helpful.